# Recommended way to use GraphQL in Next.js app

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, react-apollo, strapi

In my apps, I am using following **NPM modules** to play with [Strapi](https://strapi.io/), [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) and [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/):

- [react-apollo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-apollo)
- [next-apollo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-apollo)
- [graphql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql)
- [gql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gql)
- [recompose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recompose)

In the next step, I am creating Apollo config file, example below:

```
import { HttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { withData } from "next-apollo";

const config = {
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: "http://localhost:1337/graphql",
  })
};
export default withData(config);
```

and then inside a class component, I am using a static method `getInitialProps()` to fetch data from the Strapi via GraphQL query.

Everything is fine but maybe there is another, better way via React hooks or any other?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/UnlyEd/next-right-now, it's a boilerplate with built-in GraphQL support, you may find it easier to get started with, or could use it as a learning resource. See https://github.com/UnlyEd/next-right-now/blob/master/src/pages/index.tsx#L68 for GraphQL query usage. Also, it uses TypeScript and has built-in GraphQL autocompletion in WebStorm.

Comment: Also check out the 1st party examples: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples. There are several stripped down graphql examples (they have graphql in their name)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found one more nice hook solution for Next.js and GraphQL.

I want to share it with you. Let's start.

**Note:** I assume that you have Next.js application already installed. If not please follow this [guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started).

To build this solution we need:

- [@apollo/react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@apollo/react-hooks)
- [apollo-cache-inmemory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-cache-inmemory)
- [apollo-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-client)
- [apollo-link-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-link-http)
- [graphql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql)
- [graphql-tag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-tag)
- [isomorphic-unfetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-unfetch)
- [next-with-apollo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-with-apollo)

**1.** run npm command:

```
npm install --save @apollo/react-hooks apollo-cache-inmemory apollo-client apollo-link-http graphql graphql-tag isomorphic-unfetch next-with-apollo
```

**2.** create Appolo config file, eg. in folder `./config` and call it `appollo.js`. File code below:

```
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import withApollo from "next-with-apollo";
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";

const GRAPHQL_URL = process.env.BACKEND_URL || "https://api.graphql.url";

const link = createHttpLink({
  fetch,
  uri: GRAPHQL_URL
});

export default withApollo(
  ({ initialState }) =>
    new ApolloClient({
      link: link,
      cache: new InMemoryCache()
        .restore(initialState || {})
    })
);
```

**3.** create `_app.js` file (kind of wrapper) in `./pages` folder with below code:

```
import React from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import withData from "../config/apollo";

const App = ({ Component, pageProps, apollo }) => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apollo}>
      <Head>
        <title>App Title</title>
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
};

export default withData(App);
```

**4.** create reusable query component, eg. ./components/query.js

```
import React from "react";  
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

const Query = ({ children, query, id }) => {  
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(query, {
    variables: { id: id }
  });

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {JSON.stringify(error)}</p>;
  return children({ data });
};

export default Query;
```

**5.** create a component for our data fetched via GraphQL

```
import React from "react";
import Query from "../components/query";
import GRAPHQL_TEST_QUERY from "../queries/test-query";

const Example = () => {  
  return (
    <div>
      <Query query={GRAPHQL_TEST_QUERY} id={null}>
        {({ data: { graphqlData } }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {graphqlData.map((fetchedItem, i) => {
                return (
                  <div key={fetchedItem.id}>
                    {fetchedItem.name}
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Query>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

**6.** create our GraphQL query inside `./queries/test-query`. **Note:** I assume that we have access to our example data and properties `id` and `name` via GraphQL

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const GRAPHQL_TEST_QUERY = gql`
  query graphQLData {
    exampleTypeOfData {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;

export default GRAPHQL_TEST_QUERY;
```

**7.** to display our result create `index.js` file (homepage) in `./pages` folder with below code:

```
import Example from './components/example';

const Index = () => <div><Example /></div>

export default Index;
```

That's all.. enjoy and extend this solution as you want..

Answer (score 2):

I have found one more interestng solution with using [apollo-server-micro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-micro) and [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash)

**Quick guide:**

1. create Next.js app (example name: *next-app*) and install required packages

   ```
   npm i apollo-server-micro lodash
   ```
2. create required files in you Next.js app (*next-app*)

   - /next-app/pages/api/graphql/**index.js**
   - /next-app/pages/api/graphql/**resolvers.js**
   - /next-app/pages/api/graphql/**typeDefs.js**
3. add code to **index.js**

   ```
   import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-micro';
   import resolvers from './resolvers';
   import typeDefs from './TypeDef';

   const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
       typeDefs,
       resolvers,
   });

   export const config = {
       api: {
           bodyParser: false
       }
   };

   export default apolloServer.createHandler({ path: '/api/graphql' });
   ```
4. add code to **typeDefs.js**

   ```
   import { gql } from 'apollo-server-micro';

   const typeDefs = gql`
       type User {
           id: Int!
           name: String!
           age: Int
           active: Boolean!
       }
       type Query {
           getUser(id: Int): User
       }
   `;

   export default typeDefs;
   ```
5. add code to **resolvers.js**

   ```
   import lodash from 'lodash/collection';

   const users = [
       { id: 1, name: 'Mario', age: 38, active: true },
       { id: 2, name: 'Luigi', age: 40, active: true},
       { id: 3, name: 'Wario', age: 36, active: false }
   ];

   const resolvers = {
       Query: {
           getUser: (_, { id }) => {
               return lodash.find(users, { id });
           }
       }
   };

   export default resolvers;
   ```
6. test your Next.js app (*next-app*) by running below command and checking graphql URL http://localhost:3000/api/graphql

   ```
   npm run dev
   ```